# Shared buffer array not being properly updated across threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to write a program that takes chunks of an input text file, and moves them around according to a user-inputted pattern. The threads **do not** need to be synchronized or concurrent, as each one is given its own indices from the text file to work with. It is then meant to insert the characters in its assigned chunk to the appropriate place in a buffer char array.

However, whenever I run my code, only the first chunk (instead of all chunks, rearranged in the appropriate pattern) ends up in the char array. I have double checked the values passed to the Swapper class, and confirmed that the offsets and intervals are correct. Here's my (minimized) code:

**TextSwap.java**

```
public class TextSwap {
    private static String readFile(String filename, int chunkSize) throws Exception {
        String line;
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        File file = new File(filename);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            buffer.append(line);
        }
        br.close();
        return buffer.toString();
    }

    private static char[] runSwapper(String content, int chunkSize, int numChunks) {
        Interval[] intervals = new Interval[5];
        
        intervals[0] = new Interval(0,4);
        intervals[1] = new Interval(4,8);
        intervals[2] = new Interval(8,12);
        intervals[3] = new Interval(12,16);
        intervals[4] = new Interval(16,20);
        
        char[] buffer = new char[content.length()];
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[numChunks];
        for(int i = 0; i < numChunks; i++) {
            Interval current = intervals[i];
            threads[i] = new Thread(new Swapper(current, content, buffer, i * chunkSize));
            threads[i].start();
        }
        
        for(int i = 0; i < numChunks; i++) {
            try {
                threads[i].join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return buffer;
    }

    private static void writeToFile(String contents, int chunkSize, int numChunks) throws Exception {
        char[] buff = runSwapper(contents, chunkSize, contents.length() / chunkSize);
        System.out.println(buff);
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("src/proj/output.txt", "UTF-8");
        writer.print(buff);
        writer.close();
    }

    public static int getNumber(char val) {
        return Character.getNumericValue(val) - 9;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.out.println("Usage: java TextSwap <chunk size> <filename>");
            return;
        }
        String contents = "";
        int chunkSize = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        try {
            contents = readFile(args[1],chunkSize);
            writeToFile(contents, chunkSize, contents.length() / chunkSize);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error with IO: " + e.getMessage());
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

**Interval.java**

```
public class Interval {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    
    public Interval(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return this.x;
    }

    public int getY() {
         return this.y;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "(" + this.x + ", " + this.y + ")";
    }
}
```

**Swapper.java**

```
public class Swapper implements Runnable {
    private int offset;
    private Interval interval;
    private String content;
    private char[] buffer;

    public Swapper(Interval interval, String content, char[] buffer, int offset) {
        this.offset = offset;
        this.interval = interval;
        this.content = content;
        this.buffer = buffer;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO: Implement me!
        int x = interval.getX();
        int y = interval.getY();
        for(int i = x; i < (y - x); i++) {
            buffer[offset + (i - x)] = content.charAt(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Content of text file:
`AAAABBBBCCCCDDDDEEEE`

Hard-coded pattern:

`bcade`

Command + arguments:

`java TextSwap 4 letters.txt` (Where 4 is the `chunkSize`)

Desired output: `BBBBCCCCAAAADDDDEEEE`

Actual output: `AAAA`

Comment: Set a breakpoint at `for (int i = x; i < (y - x); i++) {` and look at the value of `i < y-x` for each of your threads. (Or just calculate it on paper, you only need to look at the first iteration)

Comment: @tgdavies Ah, so I'm a moron. Thank you.

Comment: I think the mistake was mixing offsets and absolute indexes in a way which ended up being confusing. And not writing unit tests. A unit test for Swapper would have pinned down the problem very quickly.